# How do you move comments to chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to initiate this feature?  Sometimes you know comments should be moved but you have to wait until 20 some odd comments come before the auto-move to chat feature pops up.  Is there a way to expedite this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only moderators can do this. Unfortunately moderation of comments is one of the few things that isn't "outsourced" to the community.

If you feel a comment should be removed then you can flag them. If you want to remove multiple (or all) comments it's usually easiest to just flag one comment or the post with "other" or "in need of moderator intervention" and explain why you feel all comments should be moved.

If you flag just one comment then be sure to mention "I didn't flag the other comments", since in the user interface *only* the flagged comments are shown (and not all of 'em).

Comment: Given this, I would like to promote it to a feature request, especially given Affable Geek's advice that comments are not for discussion and need to be monitored.  This seems like a pragmatic way for self-policing.

Comment: @KDog It's been proposed many times over the years. I'd love to have it, but thus far it's not here :-/

Comment: @KDog Well, mods are just volunteers. They can't do much more than you or I except that they have a few more buttons. You'd need input from a Stack Exchange employee. [Here's a feature request for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213694/166789) (I think there are more though).

Comment: Thanks again. It would certainly make the mods' job easier too.

Comment: That's not entirely true.  There is a feature that will suggest that you move comments to chat.  I'm not sure entirely what triggers it, but I think it goes off if 2 people are commenting back and fourth.

Comment: @SamIam Yeah, but that won't *move* existing comments, it'll copy them; so it's a bit different (and that feature was mentioned in the question, too).